# sabeis por que en win server 2019 Essentials no me sale la caracteristica de Host de escritorio remoto al instalar el rol de remote desktop service?

Tags: windows, server

Tengo un controlador de dominio secundario con un sistema operativo windows server 2019 y necesito habilitar sesiones simultanea de escritorio remoto de varios usuarios del dominio. Tengo las CAL de usuario instaladas pero aun asi no me permite la conexion.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.